# How do I select a variable amount of href attributes with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to select some variable amount of `href` attributes from a gallery using Puppeteer:

```
const GALLERY_SELECTOR = '#photosarea > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a';

let galleryImageHref = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
     return document.querySelector(sel).getAttribute('href');
}, GALLERY_SELECTOR);

console.log(  "image gallery link: " + galleryImageHref);
```

My above code works to select a single image link, however I am at a loss as to how to iterate through whatever number of images may be in the gallery I am trying to crawl, which may be 0 or more.

Sample HTML I am crawling:

```
<div class="contentbox profilephotosarea" id="photosarea" style="width:613px;float:right;text-align:center;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/photo.php?picid=5026734&amp;u=galleryName" class="pr"><img src="/p/2020-04/galleryName/02487b00dfb51e7fe6aaa04dba9037da-thumb.jpg"></a><br></li>

        <li><a href="/photo.php?picid=5033539&amp;u=galleryName" class="pr"><img src="/p/2020-04/galleryName/f8eec9f0c2cd1db89968383cc9e6e0a5-thumb.jpg"></a><br></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How would I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change that to:

```
return [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)].map(a => a.getAttribute('href'));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still just returns one link. Even if I use an array.?

Comment: It returns an array, but there might be only one element.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to change my selector to get all `li` elements not the `nth child` only. Thanks!